# PDO query not selecting data from one table only

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My PDO query is not selecting data from one table only, all other tables work fine.

Select query:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['userSession'];

$profile = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_profiles");
$profile->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$profile_info = $profile->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array("profile_info" => $profile_info));
?>
```

if I change the select to this: `$profile = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");`

It works fine.

DB connection:

```
<?php
session_start();
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "hoidja";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the table I am trying to query:

[image]

Thats the only table where it does not select any data- (there are 3 rows).
What could be the cause?

Comment: what does `run_query function` do?

Comment: runQuery is
 public function runQuery($sql)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt;
 }

Comment: so `die and dump` the `runQuery` response and let see what you get

Comment: var_dump shows this:<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>D:\Programs\wamp\www\Hoidja.ee\PHP\class.user.php:19:</small>
<b>object</b>(<i>PDOStatement</i>)[<i>2</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'queryString' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'SELECT * FROM user_profiles'</font> <i>(length=27)</i>
</pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget to write `where clause` .

Your query would be

```
SELECT * FROM user_profiles WHERE user_id =:user_id
```

Otherwise no use for executing this

```
$profile->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
```

**Updated**

As per below messages the problem is occur due to special such as `äö etc.`

Use `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"))` in your connection string to avoid this

Comment: It's the same. It doesn't select any data at all for this table.

Comment: Either with the execute(array) or without it does not select data from that table. I tried restarting wamp, recreated the table, but nothing.

Comment: It is connected. when I query for example tbl_users, it queries all the results. but here's my connection:

Comment: change `$user_home = new USER();` to `$user_home = new Database();` because you class name is `Database`

Comment: the new USER() comes from another file: class.user.php
class USER
{ 

 private $conn;
 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->dbConnection();
  $this->conn = $db;
    }
 
 public function runQuery($sql)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt;
 }

Comment: Have your table contain data??

Comment: Can we continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110595/discussion-between-saty-and-raqulka).

Comment: use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error in page

Comment: where do I put it? on the page where I run the select query?

Comment: Just top of your select query page!!

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['userSession'];

$profile = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_profiles");
$profile->execute();
$profile_info = $profile->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array("profile_info" => $profile_info));
?>

And it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: the page is just blank.

Comment: Hey! so the problem appears to be special characters like äö etc. How can I fix that?

Comment: add `, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"))` to your connection

Comment: Okay so now I see the json finally, but I get these symbols:; asvataja\/\u00f5petajana\/n\u00f5uandjana. How to fix that?

Comment: Use `json_encode(array("profile_info" => $profile_info), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **session_start();** above this line **header('Content-type: application/json');** in your code.

Comment: Try this $profile->execute(); instead of $profile->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

Comment: thats what I have atm:
$profile = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_profiles");
$profile->execute();

Comment: thats what I have atm:  What do you mean by this?

Comment: for the query. I removed the array.